# Reading data from a CSV file with mixing data types

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This works as long as every 'item' is numeric OR every item is alpha numeric.  When i have 'items' that are numeric AND alpha numeric it does not fill in the values correctly.

Here is the code:

```
public void updateInventory()
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(inventoryUpdateDirectory + "inventoryUpdate.csv"))
        {
            csvReader csv = new csvReader();
            DataTable inventory = csv.read(inventoryUpdateDirectory + "inventoryUpdate.csv");
            //int test = inventory.Rows.Count;
            string sql = "";

            foreach (DataRow inventoryItem in inventory.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    sql = " Update Inventory set OnHand = " + inventoryItem[1] + " WHERE Sku = '" + inventoryItem[0].ToString().Trim() + "'";
                    //executeSQL(sql);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            File.Delete(inventoryUpdateDirectory + "inventoryUpdate.csv");
        }
        else
        {
            writeToFile("fileDoesntExist", inventoryUpdateDirectory + "error.txt");
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Here is the file it reads:

```
ALB001,0
ALB002,66
10001,0
10016,348
```

This will work:

```
ALB001,0
ALB002,66
```

This will work:

```
10001,0
10016,348
```

This will not work:

```
ALB001,0
ALB002,66
10001,0
10016,348
```

It fills out the `inventoryItem` array as an empty `{}`

```
+       inventoryItem[0]    {}  object {System.DBNull}
```

Which should have the value of `ALB001`

The first 'column' in the CSV should always be treated as a string as it can contain numbers of letters, the second 'column' will always be numbers.

Anyone able to help me figure this out?

I think I just need to edit the sql query to cast them as a string but I'm not sure.

CSV READER EDIT:

```
namespace CSV
{
    public class csvReader
    {
        public DataTable read(string strFileName)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited\"");
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("CSV File");
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }

        public DataTable read(string strFileName, bool firstRowHeaders)
        {
            string hdr = "NO";
            if (firstRowHeaders) { hdr = "YES"; }

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=" + hdr + ";FMT=Delimited\"");
            conn.Open();
            string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("CSV File");
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use inline SQL, use parameters and define your DataTypes.

Comment: This was done by another developer who is no longer here, rewriting this is not an option at the moment.

Comment: What is a csvReader? It 's almost certain that the problem starts there

Comment: It's failing because the first value "OnHand" is going to be implied by the first value it sees string, but you change this a few lines later to a int.  Your best best is to wrap the value with '' to tell SQL it's always getting a string

Comment: That is a hidden SQL-Injection file. Always use parameters if you don't have full control over the input. And empty catch blocks are much worse than no try/catch.

Comment: I updated the code to include the csvreader class.  I would not write it this way, but, I don't have the time to re-write it either, it's a quick bug fix of another developer.

Comment: @Zachary for the Sku part I already surround this in single ticks.  The data is corrupt when it is filled into the DataSet.  Is there anyway to force it to a string here? `"SELECT * FROM [` I think that is where it is breaking it gathers the data, then fills it into the DataSet and corrupts the data at that point with empty values.

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint after you call read, maybe the read is not finding the data because of the datatype change.

Comment: @Zachary that is my guess, it will read it fine if they are all numbers, or it will read it fine if they are all a combination of letters and numbers.  as soon as it has both the data is corrupt.  Going to try and example on a link provided by Koby below.

Comment: Here is example how to parse using a StreamReader.  http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/building-a-simple-csv-parser-in-csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is obviously in the CsvReader class. Since you didn't attached its source code it is hard to know why it is not filling that datatable with the content and the best I can do is guess.

I will try to help you by suggesting you to use this csv reader from codeproject: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86973/C-CSV-Reader-and-Writer

you will not need to work with data tables as it enables you to iterate over the file rows using simple while loop. Your code will look like:

```
using (CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(FilePath, Encoding.Default))
{
   while (reader.ReadNextRecord())
   {
          sql = " Update Inventory set OnHand = " + reader.Fields[1] + " WHERE Sku = '" + reader.Fields[0] + "'";
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, according to the code you posted, you don't have much control on how the CSV is generated. I strongyl suggest to replace the CsvReader to the one I suggested in my answer. It is reliable, very fast and most importantly it gives you full control about how to read the csv file. I am strongly suggesting you like others did, not to use explicit SQL queries but to use parameters. Your application is highly exposed to sql injections

Comment: I completely agree with you, if I could re-write this I would (all the stuff I use has using statement, parameters etc).  I just have to listen to the guys above.  I will look at the example you posted and see if I can make quick work of it. :)

Comment: I downloaded and chucked this into the existing project and used your above example and it works like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question and I have tried many things to resolve an issue similar to this so I thought I would offer my solution.  Even though I am using C# you can inherit VB libraries and the TextFieldParser library handles this very well.  For my data I don't know how many columns will be imported though every row will be the same number of columns.  Some columns contain commas but are not surrounded by quotes "". I created a DataTable first casting all columns to string where I will validate types later. I also delete the header row which the file has that I use to create the DataTable first.  I hope this can help someone.

Data Example of what I was working with:

> Header1,Header2,Header3
>  A,123,A
>  B,123,A
>  C,A,Somedata, then
>   some more data

Here is the solution I ultimately came up with that works great.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

        private static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path)
        {
            var dataTable = new DataTable("ImportData");
            var rows = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            var columns = rows[0].Split(',');
            foreach (var column in columns)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(column.Trim(), typeof(string)));
            }
            using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
            {
                parser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
                while (true)
                {
                    var parts = parser.ReadFields();
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(parts);
                    if (parser.EndOfData) break;
                }
            }
            dataTable.Rows[0].Delete();
            return dataTable;
        }
```

Comment: Helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, I added single quotes around the OnHand value, to tell SQL it should always expect a string.  Your still better off changing your SQL statement to use "@Parameters" and assign the values inline.

```
sql = " Update Inventory set OnHand = '" + inventoryItem[1] + "' WHERE Sku = '" + inventoryItem[0].ToString().Trim() + "'";
```

Comment: This did not fix it.  The OnHand will always be a number anyways.  It is the Sku (which has single ticks) that can be a number or alpha numeric.  I was hoping this might fix it, but the same issue as before. =(

Answer (score 0):

You can read CSV with LINQ

```
var data = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName).AsParallel()
            select line.Split(',')).ToList();
```

Then do the proper casting, updating.

Comment: Would this require me to spend a lot of time re-writing the existing code to work with this new object?  I'm just looking for the simplest solution to make the existing code base work.  I'm still a noob to asp.net as well which gives me the shivers rewriting this existing stuff.

Comment: Split using comma is not compliant with csv specifications. For example if the value of the first column contains comma itself then it will produce results with 3 columns instead of 2. However it can be easily translated to csv-complaint code by calling to a mehtod that "safe splits" the line instead of the Line.Split call

Comment: As i can see it would take you a couple of minutes as you have a list to fill your datatable. Also it would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: @KobyMizrahy i don't see a problem here for reading well structured CSV data. Also you can add Skip(1) to skip column headers. ReadAllLines returns an array of strings. Each string contains a single line of the file. ReadAllText returns a single string containing all the lines of the file and the resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed.

Comment: @plurby - All I wanted to emphesize is that splitting csv data using comma is not compliant with the CSV specifications. For example if you want to save the value "I am a string that contains, comma", it will be saved with the double quotes. The csv reader should explicitly handle such scenario otherwise it will cause the above string to be spliteed to 2 different columns which is not wanted.

Comment: @plurby I am having trouble getting this to work as I feared.  How do I use the above and fill it into the existing structure?  I tried to use this and fill it into the DataSet, the adapter.  Any idea what I am missing here?